# Constant Contact Id

Tags: android, api, android-contacts

Is there any kind of contact variable that is persistent between ROM flashes or factory resets ? I created an app that looks for the contacts id but apparently that changes when there is a sync from a factory reset or new ROM (and between devices). I need to store a unique identifier. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sim data maybe you might figure out something. But if you are talking about an unique identifier the only efficient way i know is generating a UUID key and storing it locally and externally, as suggested by Reto Meier at Google I/O 2011. Here is my snippet (Don't mind my javadoc style ^^);

```
/**
 * This is just a local solution. For world-wide usage,
 * backup on a cloud is encouraged.
 * 
 * @reference Reto Meier - Google I/O 2011
 * 
 * @param context for accessing related shared preferences file
 * @return unique id
 */
public synchronized static String getUniqueId(Context context)
{
    String uniqueID;

    //Open shared preferences file for PREF_UNIQUE_ID
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //Fetch id, if any.
    uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);

    //If no id saved into shared preferences before generate new one
    if(uniqueID == null)
    {
        uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
        editor.commit();
    }

    return uniqueID;
}
```

Comment: No, not SIM data. Contact table from being syncing with your google account.